# How should you organise frontend Typescript server calls and types with backend responses that need to be joined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, frontend, backend

For example's sake, let's say I have a table with two foreign keys:

```sql
CREATE TABLE example (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  foo_id INT REFERENCES foo(foo_id),
  bar_id INT REFERENCES bar(bar_id),
  ...
);
```

I have written a thin wrapper around the `fetch` API with Typescript, and my current types which reflect my DB schema look something like ...

```js
type Example = {
  id: number;
  foo_id: number;
  bar_id: number;
  ...
}
```

... with the rest of my request/response types for POST, PATCH, etc, relative to `Example` with `Partial`, `Omit`, etc.

The problem with this design is that whenever I want to display something of type `Example` in a user friendly way, I need to turn `foo_id` and `bar_id` into objects that actually contain data I can display (such as a `name` field), i.e., populated objects of type `Foo` and `Bar`. With React Query, that involves two more queries, and consequently more error/loading checks.

So I thought maybe I should have declared my frontend type as:

```js
type Example = {
  id: number;
  foo: Foo;
  bar: Bar;
  ....
}
```

And write my backend calls to return entire `Foo` and `Bar` objects (through joins, for example). However, having to pass around entire Foo and Bar objects that I might not necessarily need feels silly, but it feels even sillier to have every endpoint return responses of different shape; I'd need to write frontend types for every shape I could have (as far as I understand it, at least). Moreover, defining and using types for POST, PATCH, etc, becomes messier (e.g., a POST needs just the ids, not the entire objects, and so would need an entirely separate type not built from others).

I've been told Prisma/GraphQL is the solution to my problems, but I am curious how one would navigate through this if they weren't feasible options to adopt yet. I'd love to use code generators, but that isn't possible with this project at the moment either, unfortunately.

Comment: This is a limitation of your normalized database design. You can either 1. have the server make the db calls to populate those references and return the structure that your front end wants. Or, 2. create a cache list of these view objects.

Comment: I wouldn't think of creating intermediary data structures as a big deal. After all, the api consumers should only be aware of the surface. Everything else are details that should be internalized.